# ssh permission denied(public key)

Tags: ssh

I have just installed VirtualBox and Vagrant on my coputer and initialized a ubuntu/bento-16.04 box. I have added a new user beside vagrant user and I have generated and copied the public key on the server in a file named authorized_keys. I also disbaled the possibility to authenticate with a paswword.

The problem is that i can connect to the server only if a provide to the ssh command the full path to my private key (located on the C drive of my computer), under -i flag.

If a try to connect just with *ssh -p 2222 lucian@localhost* i got this message: 
**permission denied(public key)**

Is there any way i cann connect  by ssh without providing the full path to the private key located on my computer?

My impression is that the server does not know about the location of the private key.

I red the earlier threads related to this issue but i can figure out what am I suppose to do to make the ssh-agent provide to the server the private key automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to type vagrant ssh? you have to have the private key of the vagrant user you just created in your computer as well and the vagrant guest should have your private key as well

Comment: Hi Yien!vagrant ssh works fine! I just want to connect to the server with the new user I have created, but without providing the full path to the private key file every time.

Comment: after you generate the keys did you change directory where it should be restored? or just the default one? edit /etc/sshd_config and add the location where ssh needs to look into.

Comment: no I did not change it. what entry I should edit in sshd_config file? or i just need to add a new one specifying the location of the IdentityFile

Comment: oh you can edit this one first, in ~/.ssh/config and add this one `IdentityFile /path/to/identity`

Comment: I have edited etc/ssh/ssh_config and added the path to the private key. Are you referring to a file located under home/user/.ssh/? i do not have any config file in this location. Do I need to create one?

Comment: yes you can create one.  here is the simple entry of it 

`Host server1
     HostName serverip/server.domain.
     User username
     Port 2222
     IdentityFile /path/to/your/identity/id_rsa

for more information about this kindly visit this link: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Comment: I red the article. My config file shows like this
Host server1 Host Name 127.0.0.1 port 2222 IdentityFile path/to/private key User lucian Still something does not work. Probably i do not provide the correct host name. How can I find the hostname?

Comment: type `hostname - - fqdn` in the command line and it will return your hostname same as with your guest to point it out

Comment: on the server `hostname --fqdn` returns vagrant.vm and on my local machine returns the name of my computer. Neither one works. After i have added `config.ssh.private_key_path`, `config.ssh.username` and `config.ssh.port`in the VagrantFile I can log as the new user with `vagrant ssh` command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it by creating a config file stored on the local machine (*~/.ssh/config*) with the following content

`Host myhost
      HostName 192.168.10.10
      User username 
      IdentityFile /path/to/identity file
      IdentitiesOnly yes`

where

- `myhost` is any name you choose to use together with ssh command for
  connecting to the server
- `HostName` is the IP address set in the Vagrantfile for private network
- `user` is the name of the new user created at the server level
- `IdentityFile` is the path to the private key stored locally (public key being stored on the server in the authorized_keys file)

After that i can connect to the server from vagrant simply with the command *ssh myhost*.

Comment: You should add that _"a config file stored on the local machine"_ is not some arbitrary config file but exactly `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 1):

Without editing files, you can use `ssh-add yourkeyfile`, it won't survive a reboot though.

To configure it as a permanent setting you can create or edit the following file

`nano /home/yourusername/.ssh/config`

Add the following entry

```
Host serverIP/FQDN
IdentityFile /home/yourusername/.ssh/yourkeyfile (or other path)
```

Now every time you connect to that specific host it will use that file.

You can also add the port number and username in the above configuration so that you only need to type `ssh remotehostname` to connect.

To do that add

```
 User remote_username
 Port remote_port#
```

Comment: I have tried to do that and does not work.I received this message: could not resolve hostname. My impression is that i am not providing correctly the IP of the host. Is this the ip that  appears  in VagrantFile when i configured the access based on private network option? How can I find this IP?

Comment: If a run vagrant ssh-config hostname appears as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ah shoot, missed the vagrant tie in.  Have you set `config.ssh.private_key_path` in the vagrantfile? https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

Comment: I did it now, but after running vagrant reload, vagrant cannot connect anymore to the box and the command vagrant ssh doe not work anymore. I can still connect with the other user (but only if i provide the full path to the private key). Do I need to have the private key file on ther server, too?

Comment: You have to set all of the settings for the host in the same vagrantfile once you set one of the settings otherwise everything else will be going through the default that vagrant ships with.

Comment: So this means that i cannot use both vagrant default user and the user created by me? And what exactly I am supposed to set in the VagrantFile? can you be more specific?

Comment: I have configured in the VagrantFile to following entries: config.ssh.private_key_path, config.ssh.username, config.ssh.port. The result is that VM is booting based on the new user and vagrant ssh command does not work anymore. However for connecting to the server itself still I need to provide the path to the private_key

Comment: Found out that by running vagrant ssh I connect to the server as the new user (asking the passphrase attached to the private key)